# Submit form via Ajax and respond to client based on API response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which needs to be submitted to a CRM via an API. The API then sends a response in JSON which I need to use to provide feedback to the person submitting the form.

```
if(error=='0'){
    var FormData= $("#mailform").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: FormData,
            beforeSend:function() {
                $("#mailform").css('opacity','0.5');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#rest_btn').trigger('click');
                window.location.href = "thankyou.html?n="+name;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once I grab all the fields in `action.php`, how do I submit to a page on a subdomain (ie. `crm.domain.com/webform`) and respond based on API response?

Comment: or would it be better to avoid Ajax completely?

Comment: As you are going to load a new page regardless of the response from the PHP script. It would seem that AJAX is unnecessary in this case. I would just use a normal SUBMIT and the in the PHP do a `header()` to the new page

Comment: @RiggsFolly - what would be the best way to do this? I need to make the response dependable on the response of the API

Comment: It's not really clear where you're stuck.  Are you going to submit to the subdomain page from server-side code or client-side code?  If the former, why are you focusing on client-side code here?  If the latter, what have you tried?  You're already performing an AJAX POST, so why not simply perform another one?

Comment: So what are the 2 possible response actions. You do not make that clear in your script, there is no testing of the data returned from the PHP script

Comment: The current script in `action.php` is just an email form, we are just integrating with the API. TBH - I have no idea where to start in the `action.php`. Client fills out the form, submits, this goes to the CRM and based on JSON response I provide feedback to client.

Comment: If you dont know what you want to do, it makes us suggesting how to do it **quite impossible**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just described what I want to do - submit to CRM and act based on response... if you don't want to help - that's fine.

Comment: It sounds, that you want to send the form-data to action.php to work with the data, but in your comments you write that you want to send it to another domain? is that true? Could you post a sequence diagramm, so everybody understands what your goal is? Do you have any errors, where you need our help?

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in syntax , you need to remove one } at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it will help you.Let's try..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
if(error=='0'){
    var FormData= $("#mailform").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://crm.domain.com/webform',
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'JSON',
            data: FormData,
            beforeSend:function() {
                $("#mailform").css('opacity','0.5');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var data=eval(response);
                name=data.name; //name field must be return from http://crm.domain.com/webform in json format


    $('#rest_btn').trigger('click');
            window.location.href = "thankyou.html?n="+name;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this runs into same-origin-error, isn't it?